# Installing a windows service as another user than Network Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, access-control

I am using a self-installing variant to install my windows service. That means I run the exe that makes up the service, and when run it installs itself using the following line of code:

```
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
```

This works fine, and the service gets added to the list of services. My only problem is that this service gets added with **Log On As** equal to *Network Service*. I am doing certain operations from this service that require it to log on as *Local System*.

How can I make it install itself to run as *Local System* instead of *Network Service*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using `ServiceProcessInstaller`. If so, you can set `ServiceAccount.LocalSystem` to its `Account` property